# Failed to pull image repository does not exist or may require 'docker login':

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-registry, kubernetes-secrets

I am receiving this error when starting a Pod

```
Failed to pull image "docker-username/docker-private-repository:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker-username/docker-private-repository, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

My setup is as follow:

Ceated a Secret service using command line

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry docker-keys --docker-username=docker-username --docker-password=password --docker-email=docker-email@gmail.com --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v1
```

which generates the following data inside secrets

```
kubectl get secret docker-keys -o json | jq '.data | map_values(@base64d)'
{
  ".dockerconfigjson": "{\"auths\":{\"https://index.docker.io/v1\":{\"username\":\"docker-username\",\"password\":\"password\",\"email\":\"docker-email@gmail.com\",\"auth\":\"base64encodedtoken\"}}}"
}
```

Then in deployment I am using `docker-keys` secrets

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-private-repository
  labels:
    app: docker-private-repository
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-private-repository
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-private-repository
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-keys
      containers:
        - name: docker-private-repository
          image: docker-username/docker-private-repository:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

I did tried to search for a solution, but always ended up with the above setup.

**Update1:**
Secrets service and pod are running in the same namespace `default`.
Pulling manually from docker-hub works

```
docker pull docker-username/docker-private-repository:latest
latest: Pulling from docker-username/docker-private-repository
0ecb575e629c: Already exists 
...
7467d1831b69: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:153643ecb19c2ce54635839ce9393b2e256ce6c34a2fe75b91c7a41525a6a535
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker-username/docker-private-repository:latest
docker.io/docker-username/docker-private-repository:latest
```

**Update2** `kubectl describe pod`

I have 2 sercrets services, one for dockerhub credentials and another is `token-rzlx6` for whatever reason.
Thing is when I run describe pod, I don't see the secrets for dockerhub to be mounted as `token-rzlx6`, could this be the reason? And why it is not mounted?

```
...
Volumes:
  default-token-rzlx6:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-rzlx6
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
...
```

Comment: If you manually run `docker login user pass` on your local system, can you pull your image?

Comment: @AliTou docker login is successful, and I pushed my image to dockerhub, so I assumed pull would work as well. I tried anyway. 
`Status: Downloaded newer image for docker-user/docker-private-repo:latest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was the docker-server value. Based on tutorials I've watched I was using api V1, while my image was pushed/created to dockerhub with V2, may be it's not relevant and V1 was deprecated. When I create a secret service I need to use V2 server `https://index.docker.io/v2/`, like:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry docker-keys \
  --docker-username=yyyyyy \
  --docker-password=xxxxx \
  --docker-email=my@mail.com \
  --docker-server=https://index.docker.io/v2/
```

A simple thing, that took days to discover, as many articles have V1 or it's not showing it at all or using private docker registry. Docs are here. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

**Update:**

One more thing why I wasn't paying attention to API version is `docker config` file, that has V1 as API and from here I took the endpoint to create secret service, while it worked with V2 only.

```
cat ~/.docker/config.json                                                 
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "osxkeychain"
}%
```

**Update 2:**
However, when I pulled image locally with `docker pull` command, image was pulled successfully using v1 url. Assumption is, api V1 works within docker, but not in kubernetes.

Comment: I have this issue right now and unfortunately this didn't seem to fix it in my case on a cluster on DO :(

Answer (score 0):

i was having this issue, if i change my repository to public it works.

Comment: Public repository means anyone can download your docker image, this is not what you want when working on a private/commercial application.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. But you have a limited number of free private repos. But for some reason Docker will not stop you from uploading private repos beyond that limit. But it will trigger this error when you try to pull them. That’s why changing to public “solves” the issue.